# Any custom resulution in ubuntu 22.04 doesnt work

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

I want to use custom resolution on my ubuntu, i have tried using cvt and umc,and i can select and use custom resolutions in my settings. The problem is that my display starting lagging and flashing like it got hit by a rock. any custom resolution doesnt work, no matter of width and height or hz. ( I have FHD 144hz eDP monitor on my laptop.(HP PAvilion gaming 15.6, ryzen 7 4800h, nvidia geforce 1660ti with max-q design. all drivers are isntalled))

Edit: when i use 1440x1080, my screen starts flashing, when i use any other custom resolution - it goes black.

Edit: even preset resolutions doesnt work, only one that working that 1920x1080 144hz